# Bad Request for POST method

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to POST the response using below code.

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
          req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer *****************');
          //req.setBody('');
          req.setBody('{"name":"testrv","description":"Yearly description","campaignCode":"12345qwerty","color":"red","favorite":false}');
        Http http = new Http();
          system.debug('test');

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);       
        system.debug(res.getBody());
```

But getting the error as

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

But when i tried to GET the response it is working fine.When I tried with POST & DELETE geting error as Bad Request. Any suggestions please

Comment: I can see you are sending body as blank

Comment: Its a mistake & Edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createCampaign.htm) for campaigns states clearly that several fields are required:

Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com

```
POST /hub/v1/campaigns
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "name": "Annual Sale 2012",
    "description": "Yearly sale",
    "campaignCode": "annual2012",
    "color": "0000ff",
    "favorite": false
}
```

Your POST body is:

```
req.setBody('');
```

You commented out:

```
req.setBody('{"name":"testrv","description":"Yearly description","campaignCode":"12345qwerty","color":"red","favorite":false}')
```

The doc states `color` must be a hexcode value.

Comment: I tried encoding the code also as "color":"#ff0000" but no luck.